# How to give a player velocity from only one key press at a time LibGDX Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a player the moves through the pressing of arrow keys which give him velocity. Everything works fine, the only problem is that the player goes faster than normal when more than one arrow key is pressed. I assume this is because both these arrow keys are increasing the player's velocity at the same time. My question is how would I prevent this from happening, meaning that when more than one arrow key is pressed the player gains the usual amount of velocity. Any help is appreciated Code is below.

```
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2) {
        player.b2Body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0), player.b2Body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) {
        player.b2Body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2Body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) == Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
        player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)
        player.b2Body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 2f), player.b2Body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y >= -2)
        player.b2Body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, -2f), player.b2Body.getWorldCenter(), true);
```

Comment: Could you just add another `if` statement to detect if multiple keys are being pressed, and if so, divide the speed by `Math.sqrt(2D)`?

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought but I can’t figure out how to detect multiple keys being pressed.

Comment: Well I've never used [tag:libgdx] or [tag:box2d], but I would figure you could just put something like `if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))) {` to detect if the player is going at a 45-degree angle by pressing two keys.

Comment: A hint that will save you problems in future. Never create a new Vector as you are. This will cause new objects to be created in your render cycle and discarded when you loose the reference to them. Your memory usage creeps up and eventually garbage collection will come and clear up your discarded objects (in this case your Vector2's). Garbage collection is expensive and will cause your frame rate to jitter - noticably.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should calculate your combined movement vector before normalising and applying as an impulse if you need to. You can use something like this:

```
var x = 0f
var y = 0f
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
    x -= -1
}
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
    x += 1
}
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
    y += 2
}
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
    y -= 2
}
val movementVector = Vector2(x,y)
// Now you have your combined movement vector that you should normalise and you can apply as a single impulse
```